# How do I use angular to post array of complex objects to MVC?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, binding

I am trying to convert a traditional **ASP.NET MVC** postback view to use **Angular** and **AJAX** postbacks. My problem is that I am unable to determine the **binding** to get the proper values sent up to the server.

With the traditional form, the postback values looked like

```
Request.SearchTerms = "error 123"
Request.Facets.Index = 0
Request.Facets[0].Field = "priority"
Request.Facets[0].Value = "low"
Request.Facets.Index = 3
Request.Facets[3].Field = "priority"
Request.Facets[3].Value = "medium"
Request.Facets.Index = 8
Request.Facets[8].Field = "state"
Request.Facets[8].Value = "open"
```

This in turn gets bound (using MVC model binding) on the ASP.NET side to an object like

```
public class Request {
   public string SearchTerms { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Facet> Facets { get; set; }
}

public class Facet {
   public string Field { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The `SearchTerms` binding is simple. Something like the following works.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Request.SearchTerms" />
```

My question is how to configure/bind using **Angular** and postback the **Facets** fields in the format specified at the beginning of the question.

Comment: If the MVC end cannot be modified and you must send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as shown above, then you will need to do something like this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Thanks Phil. I will read this over the weekend to see if it solves my issue.